# Google Sheets conditional formatting based on cell above it

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a column of blank cells. If I type something into a cell, I want the cell immediately below that one to turn red. Any ideas for conditional formatting help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom formula:
`=not(isblank(offset(A1,-1,0)))`

The only problem that I can see is that A1 is automatically highlighted, regardless of any value in any other cell

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps

select cell b1

set conditional Format, say for Column B

apply to Range: B2:B  (>it will later correct to B2:B999 or max rows)

Format Rules

Custom Formula: `=not(isblank(b1))`  >>fill RED

...done

if for some reason, like not selecting B1 at the beginning the formula (upon inspection) is different, pls correct to ...B1...